# Refugee Terrorism Rate Statistics

Tags: politics, terrorism

As per this Washington Times article [Trump signs new extreme vetting order](http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2017/mar/6/trump-sign-new-extreme-vetting-order/):

> Supporting claims that the U.S. is at risk because of its refugee policies, administration officials said that of the FBI’s 1,000 ongoing anti-terrorism investigations, 300 cases involved suspected terrorists who came to the country as refugees."

First of all, are there really only 1,000 active anti-terrorism cases going on? And is this 300 number accurate?